# Passing dictionary to REST API

Tags: dictionary, nancy

I need to POST a key pair value dictionary to the REST API. I am using NancyFx framework for binding parameters

Server side property:

```
    public Dictionary<string, string> foo { get; set; }
```

Client side code:

```
            var bar = [];
            bar["one"] = "First";
            bar["two"] = "Second";

            var UserModel = {
                someotherpar: "abc",
                foo: bar
            };
            $.ajax({
                url: 'myEndpoint',
                type: 'POST',
                contentType: 'application/json',
                data: JSON.stringify(UserModel),
                success: function (data, textStatus, jqXHR) {

                   }    
            });
```

Answer (score 0):

This was possible with the use of SortedList and not Dictionary.